# What is the meaning of the proof in the appendix?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

I am trying to understand this proof

[image]

I kind of understand what the proof is but I am a confused by the appendix. I don't understand what appendix 3(a) proves or how it implies that there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$. Does anyone know what it means?

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does X with a dot over it mean? What does the next symbol mean?  How is pi[AxB] different than AxB?  I think the theorem in the apendix is called the tube lemma.  Heavy use of symbolic logic makes it hard to be sure.

Comment: @WilliamElliot, It just $X$, the dot is print error because the book is old.

Comment: @WilliamElliot, the function $\pi$ is called continuous action. I am studying course in dynamical systems and we are following the book "Elements of dynamical systems" by J. de Vries.